# How to add an extension to generic type?

Tags: swift, generics, swift2

I have a generic type that I would like to add an extension for, but the compiler is complaining about that the generic is not declared.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
public class MyGenericType<T> {
    let abc = 123
}

extension MyGenericType<T> { // Error: Use of undeclared type 'T'

    public convenience init(value: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.init()

        print(value)
    }

}
```

Is it possible to add an extension to `MyGenericType<T>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
extension MyGenericType {
    public convenience init(value: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.init()
        print(value)
    }
}
```

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID185):

> When you extend a generic type, you do not provide a type parameter list as part of the extension’s definition. Instead, the type parameter list from the *original* type definition is available within the body of the extension, and the original type parameter names are used to refer to the type parameters from the original definition.

Comment: But how to I make the 2nd parameter in the `convenience init` a generic type?

Comment: You just use `T`.  See the addition to the reply with the quote from documentation.